# joomla getMailer() not working as expected

Tags: php, email, joomla, frameworks, mailer

im trying to use joomla mailer to send emails but it doesent work, any suggestions? what am i missing? i've searched around the web and SO, but it didnt help.

the only error i get is 500, and i cant understand why...

this is the actual code:

```
<?php
//framework joomla
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); 
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../"));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

//get vars
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$num1 = $session->get('variable1');  
$num2 = $session->get('variable2');  
$val= $session->get('variable3');  
$uq= $session->get('unique');
$sendto= $session->get('mail');

//mail
$mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
$mailer->setSender('some1@domain.com');
$recipient = array($sendto, 'some1else@domain.com');
$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);


$body   = '<h2>sometext</h2>'
    . '<div>sometext</div>'
    . '<div> blabla' echo $num1 'blabla </div>'
    . '<div> texttext' echo $num2 'texet </div>'
    . '<div> texttext' echo $val 'text </div>';

$mailer->isHTML(true);
$mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
$mailer->setBody($body);
$mailer->AddEmbeddedImage("$uq".".gif", "image_0", "", "base64", "image/gif");
$mailer->addAttachment("$uq".".gif");  

//send 
$send =& $mailer->Send();
if ( $send !== true ) {
    //Elimina .gif 
    $mask = "*.gif";
    array_map( "unlink", glob( $mask ) );
    unset($mailer); 
    echo 'error: ' . $send->message;
} else {
unset($mailer);
    //Elimina .gif 
    $mask = "*.gif";
    array_map( "unlink", glob( $mask ) );
    echo 'done';
}
?>
```

forgot to add specs about the platform:

PHP Version 5.3.22

Joomla! Version 2.5.9

if you need any other info just ask.

update:
i tried another joomla! version, a simplified version of the code without variables and with a single email, plain text emails... nothing seems to work.
internal server error (500) with a blank error log... (wierd, but the installation it's inside a subdirectory with many other installation, and my webhosting allow me to see only the "root" log, so i think this is the problem of the blank error log...)

Comment: Error 500: look into the error.log of your web server. There should be info about your error.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure whether this is the root of your problem. But $mail->setSender() accepts an array. Example : $mail->setSender(array('SENDER EMAIL', 'SENDER NAME'));

AND

$mail->addRecipient() accepts a string OR an array. Use an array if you are sending the email to multiple recipients and the string when you are sending the email to only 1 recipient.

Hope this helps

Comment: $mail->setSender() accepts strings (only email address) or array (email and name). thanks for the answer but nothing changes if i put arrays or strings in both setSender or addRecipient...

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved!

this might help someone else so, here is how:

```
$config =& JFactory::getConfig();
```

this line grabs the email configuration of Joomla, without this Jmail will not send emails.

```
//body email
$body   .= "<h2>Texttext</h2>" . "\n";
$body   .= "<div>TexttextTexttextTexttext" . $blockh .  " Texttext " . $blockd . "\n";
$body   .= "<div> TexttextTexttext <span> " .  $num1 . " </span> Texttext </div>" . "\n";
$body   .= "<div>TexttextTexttextTexttext <span> " .  $val . " </span> Texttext </div>";
```

previus concatenation of the body was not working, it seems that double quotes are needed to work...

```
$mailer->isHTML();
```

the "true" inside is not necessary since true is the default value..

Answer (score 0):

In answer to KentaS comment of

> previus concatenation of the body was not working, it seems that double quotes are needed to work...

It has *nothing* to do with single or double quotes. 
In your original post you had:

```
$body   = '<h2>sometext</h2>'
. '<div>sometext</div>'
. '<div> blabla' echo $num1 'blabla </div>'
. '<div> texttext' echo $num2 'texet </div>'
. '<div> texttext' echo $val 'text </div>';
```

the part:

```
'<div> blabla' echo $num1 'blabla </div>'
```

causes a syntax error (string, followed, without concatenation, by a call to "echo", followed, without concatenation, by a string...!

Somthing which works with single quotes:

```
$body   = '<h2>sometext</h2>'
. '<div>sometext</div>'
. '<div> blabla' . $num1 . 'blabla </div>'
. '<div> texttext' . $num2 . 'texet </div>'
. '<div> texttext' . $val . 'text </div>';
```

And with double quotes you can do even shorter:

```
$body   = "<h2>sometext</h2>"
. "<div>sometext</div>"
. "<div> blabla $num1 blabla </div>"
. "<div> texttext $num2 texet </div>"
. "<div> texttext $val text </div>";
```

Cheers,

Dom